# Django adding two objects to view

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi quite new to django and working with a gallery. What i want is to get two objects in one and im still clueless after 3 hours.

Using photologue for the gallery and i have a display where i want to list all galleries with the latest added image as a thumbnail

```
list_galleries = Gallery.objects.all()
g = []
for gallery in list_galleries:
    g.append(gallery.latest(limit=1, public=True))

return render_to_response('gallery/list_galleries.html', {'list_galleries': list_galleries, 'images': g})
```

I have tried this but i cant seem to find a way to get the key of the list_galleries for loop without breaking it.

my view:

```
{% for gallery in list_galleries %}

<p>
<span class="title"><a href="/gallery/images/{{ gallery.title }}" >{{ gallery.title }}</a>
Here is the image: <img src="/media/{{ images.0.0.image }}" />
</span><br />
<span class="flavor">{{ e.date_added|date:"F d, Y, H:m" }}</span><br />
</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: sorry if i was unclear, this is from a view where i list all my galleries, and i want to list a image from that gallery as a thumbnail!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to merge the two lists:

```
return render_to_response('gallery/list_galleries.html',
                          {'galleries': zip(list_galleries,  g)})
```

Then in your view you can do this:

```
{% for gallery, latest in galleries %}
    <!-- your html -->
{% endfor %}
```

Where `gallery` is an item from `list_galleries` and latest is an item from `g`.

---

An even better solution however is to create a method in your `Gallery` class:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    # SQL columns

    @property
    def thumb(self):
        return self.latest(limit=1, public=True)
```

Then you don't have to create the list `g` and in your template you can simply use `gallery.thumb`.

Comment: @DanielX, you're welcome :). Take a look at my alternative suggestion as well, that's a better way to do this.